# Need help for parsing JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I'm learning how to parse JSON. I've made the raywenderlich tutorial but I'm still lost with some steps. I got my own JSON :

```
{
    "Albumvideo":{
        "album01":{
            "titreAlbum":"Publicité",
            "photoAlbum":"blabla.jpg",
            "pubVideos":{
                "pub01":[
                {
                "titrePub":"Chauffage Compris",
                "dureePub":"01'25''",
                "photoPub":"chauffage.jpg",
                "lienPub":"http://www.wmstudio.ch/videos/chauffage.mp4"
                }
                ]
            }
        },
        "album02":{
            "titreAlbum":"Events",
            "photoAlbum":"bloublou.jpg",
            "eventsVideos":{
                "event01":[
                {
                "titreEvent":"Chauffage Compris",
                "dureeEvent":"01'25''",
                "photoEvent":"chauffage.jpg",
                "lienEvent":"http://www.wmstudio.ch/videos/chauffage.mp4"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The I got my 'Code' to parse my JSON :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async (kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:lienAlbumsVideo];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray* albumsVideo = [json objectForKey:@"Albumvideo"];

    NSLog(@"Nombre d'albums : %i",[albumsVideo count]);

}
```

This works fine, my NSLog returns '2'. Where I now have difficulties is to make an array with "titreAlbum" or "event01" for example. If I do :

```
NSArray* event01 = [json objectForKey:@"event01"];
NSLog(@"Number of objects in event01 : %i ", [event01 count]);
```

My NSLog returns '0'.

I didn't really understand how to parse information from multidimensional array in a JSON. Thank's already!

Nicolas

Comment: Your Albumvideo returns a dictionary not array.

Comment: The same way you would parse it from a multidimensional array in any other situation.  There is absolutely zero difference.

Comment: *difficulties in to make an array with "titreAlbum" or "event01".* Can you elaborate this ?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a two-dimensional array. And JSON does not support this, but arrays of array (as C does and as Objective-C does).

```
NSDictionary *document = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// Getting titreAlbum
NSDictionary *albumVideo = document[@"Albumvideo"];

NSDictionary *album01 = albumVideo[@"album01"];

NSString *titreAlbum = album01[@"titreAlbum"];

// Getting an event

NSDictionary *album02 = albumVideo[@"album02"];
NSDictionary *eventVideos = album02[@"eventsVideos"];
NSArray *event01 = eventVideo[@"event01"];
```

(Typped in Safari)

You can use KVC, too, if you are not interested in the middle layers.

But your identifiers and question let me think, that the structure of your JSON is malformed.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some paths to make a better structure for my JSON?

Comment: I think, that you mismatch arrays and dictionaries. Are you a php developer? In Objective-C (and JSON) a unnamed (indexed) list of items is an array, while dictionaries (JSON: objects) are named pairs of key and value. For example I wouldn't expect event01 being an array. But, of course, I do not have detailed information about your format and needs

Comment: I've made php a long time ago. My needs for my application is : A table view with video's categories then for a detail view with the videos of selected category. For the categories I have "Title" and "Picture" and the list of videos corresponding. For every videos, I have "title", "duration", "picture" and "link". That's why I made my JSON like that but it was without real knowledges. Can you explain me where to use array and where to use dictionary? Thank's

Comment: So videos should be an array. And the items in videos should be a dictionary (JSON: object). In your Code "pubVideos":{ is a Dictionary
and "pub01" : [ is an array.

Comment: If I summarize, for my example : "Albumvideo" = array, "album01" = dictionary, "pubVideos" = array, "pub01" = dictionary. Is it exact?

Comment: As I said, I do not know your needs and structure in detail, but yes, this sounds better.

Comment: I cannot do this : NSArray* albums_video = document[@"albums_video"];
    NSDictionary* album01 = albums_video[@"album_videos"];  It gives me an error. What's the way to parse a dictionary that is in an array?

Comment: There is no way. As I said, you have to change the JSON first. If it is not possible, you simply has to accept the structure. What you can do is to put keys like "album01", "album02" to an array with the index 0 resp. 1 (it starts with 0). Is there a definition of the JSON anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I've already changed my JSON. Here is it : http://www.wmstudio.ch/videosWM.json but even that : NSArray* albums_video = document[@"albums_video"];
    
    NSLog(@"%i", [albums_video count]); returns '0'.

Comment: Hmmm, there is something wrong in your implementation.Please check the error and log it. (That's, what it is for.) Anyway you should remove the layer "albumXX". The array indexes for you. What about an e-mail? We can discuss that in german.

Answer (score 1):

Some things,
every time you see

> { ... }

in the json that is the beginning/end of an `NSDictionary`

once parsed, while

> [ ... ]

is the beginning end of an `NSArray`.

So once you parse the json using `NSJSONSerialization` you can navigate that dictionary using that knowledge.

Given the json you have to get an array of `"titreAlbum"` you would have to do something like:

```
NSDictionary *albumVideo = json[@"Albumvideo"];
NSMutableArray *albumTitres = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *album in albumVideo) {
    [albumTitres addObject:album[@"titreAlbum"]];
}
```

That said, I think your json is not malformed as is passing the JSONLint validation, but is not helping you to parse it. I would expect that the `Albumvideo` is an array of albums, instead of a dictionary of albums.

Comment: Thank you Emilio. So if I understand, Albumvideo should be an array containing 2 objects (album01 and album02) and album01 and 02 should be dictionaries?

Comment: I think so, that would allow you to interact with the json in a more rational way. But like I said the current json is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was actually trying to access [Google Distance API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ahmedabad&destination=mumbai) where i needed to get

```
{
 "routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 23.0225066,
           "lng" : 73.2544778
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 19.0718263,
           "lng" : 72.57129549999999
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Map data ©2014 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "524 km",
              "value" : 523839
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "7 hours 34 mins",
              "value" : 27222
           },
           "end_address" : "Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 19.0759856,
              "lng" : 72.8776573
           },
           "start_address" : "Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 23.0225066,
              "lng" : 72.57129549999999
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.2 km",
                    "value" : 210
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 25
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 23.0226436,
                    "lng" : 72.573224
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Head on Swami Vivekananda RdRoad/Swami Vivekananda Rd",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "uqokCsa}yLS?GYEk@Cq@@qA@eA@aADm@"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 23.0225066,
                    "lng" : 72.57129549999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              }]`
```

I needed to access routes.legs.steps.html_instructions.

So my code is as under

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ahmedabad&destination=%@",self.city]];`

NSURLResponse *res;
NSError *err;

NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] returningResponse:&res error:&err];

NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSArray *routes=dic[@"routes"];
NSArray *legs=routes[0][@"legs"];
NSArray *steps=legs[0][@"steps"];
NSMutableArray *textsteps=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *latlong=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i< [steps count]; i++){
    NSString *html=steps[i][@"html_instructions"];
    [latlong addObject:steps[i][@"end_location"]];
    [textsteps addObject:html];
}
```